# Copying a war file from GitLab CI to Tomcat

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline to build war file and deploy it to Tomcat Container from GitLab.

I am using a Maven image to build the project. Once the war file is created, I would like to copy it to some folder so that from there it can be copied to the tomcat server, in a container, webapps directory.

My current approach and goal is to use a Dockerfile in my project. From a Tomcat image, run Tomcat using the project war.  I tried using ADD in the Dockerfile but the directory paths where the war resides, $CI_PROJECT_DIR, is not where the Dockerfile is looking.

The following is the ".gitlab-ci.yml" file.

```
stages:
  # Build project
  - build
  - package
  # Build and deploy mailService
  #- deploy

variables:
  # Variables that can be used throughout the pipeline are defined here.
  
  # Maven variables
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: '-s /appdir/.m2/settings.xml'
  MAVEN_PATH: '/appdir/opt/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin'
  IMAGE_PATH: 'gitlab-registry.gs.mil/gteam-development/docker'

project-build:  
  image: ${IMAGE_PATH}/maven
  services:
    - tomcat:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - ${MAVEN_PATH}/mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean package
    - ls -als
    - ls -als target

build docker image:
  stage: package
  image: docker
  services: 
    - docker:dind
  script: 
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  tags:
    - dind
```

The following is the "Dockerfile" I am using to run Tomcat using the image.  I need to copy my war file to the Tomcat webapps folder and build another image.

```
FROM tomcat:latest

LABEL maintainer=”Jacquelyne Wilson”

# ADD $CI_PROJECT/target/geoint-rfi-data-api.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [“catalina.sh”, “run”]
```

NOTE: These images I have in our Gitlab Container Registry.  Hope this is enough information.
This is my first experience creating Gitlab CI pipeline.  My apologies if my terms and approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the WAR file built in your `project-build` job as an [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html), so it is available in the following job. By the way, you should probably not use spaces in the job name.

This could look like the following:

```
project-build:  
  image: ${IMAGE_PATH}/maven
  services:
    - tomcat:latest
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /path/to/your/war
  script:
    - ${MAVEN_PATH}/mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean package
    - ls -als
    - ls -als target
```

And in the docker build job, you can then copy the WAR file from the artifact to the docker build context path so it can be `ADD`ed to your image.

Hope this helps :)

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: Andreas, thank you for your response. The build puts the war in $CI_PROJECT/target and Docker file directory, assuming WORKDIR, is /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder424939074/target/.

Is the artifacts path a path that is visible from the Dockerfile?

Thank you for the naming tip.

Comment: The artifacts are available in the next stage(s), yes. You might need to explicitly declare that you need the artifacts, depending on your configuration.